# Google Sheets, Updating Letter Stock Quantity

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

so i sell products which have a quantity of every letter. Im trying to make a system so that i can type a word in and depending on the style selected in cell "S7" it will update the stock letter wise.

[image]

So from this picture, you would type in the cell "R7" the word that you want, then in "S7" the style. Then after pressing the button it will find the "3D Black Gels" Cloumn then minus the stock on them letters.

So for example if we used the word "TEST" with the style "3D Black Gels" it would update

"T" stock on column "C" to 98 as the letter has been used twice.
then so on with "E" going to 99 and "S" to 99.

```
 function StockUpdate() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  
  //--- Number Plates Registration (7 Chars).
  var inputReg1 = activeSheet.getRange("R9").getValues();
  var inputReg2 = activeSheet.getRange("S9").getValues();
  var inputReg3 = activeSheet.getRange("T9").getValues();
  var inputReg4 = activeSheet.getRange("U9").getValues();
  var inputReg5 = activeSheet.getRange("V9").getValues();
  var inputReg6 = activeSheet.getRange("W9").getValues();
  var inputReg7 = activeSheet.getRange("X9").getValues();
  
  //--- Number Plates Style.
  var inputStyle = activeSheet.getRange("S7").getValues();
  
  //--- Finds the column of the plate style selected and adds +1 to get to the stock column of the style.
  var textFinder = activeSheet.createTextFinder(inputStyle)
  var columnFinder = textFinder.findNext().getColumn()+1;
    
}
```

so the above was my attempt, i was probably no where close but what i was trying to do what get the value of every letter used.

To do this i used `=REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(R7), REPT("(.)", LEN(R7)))` in cell "R9"

This would split every letter into its own cell of the word typed in "R7".

i would then get the style used, and use a text finder to return the column for it.

I then added +1 as this would then produce the stock colum to the right of every letter.

from this point i am kinda stuck and think i may be doing this the wrong way and would really appricate any help.

Billy

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about the logic of `So for example if we used the word "TEST" with the style "3D Black Gels" it would update "T" stock on column "C" to 98 as the letter has been used twice. then so on with "E" going to 99 and "S" to 99.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it and your goal?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike not your fault probably mine. Makes sense in my head and probabaly not yours. So the goal im trying to acheive is: You will type a word in a cell for example "TEST" you will then pick a style in another cell for example "3D Black Gels". You will then press a button to activate script. The script needs to find the colum with the style that was in the cell and then also the letters that were used. The letters that are used in that style will then have the stock number reduced by 1

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your replying, I cannot still understand about your goal. For example, in order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample input and output you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: So if you take a look at the photo and read the following: “R7” = name “S7” = style. As we can see in the photo it says “TEST” and “3D Black Gels” there for I would like it to search “B” column as that one is for the “3D Black Gels” it will then find each letter that was used. So the text used was “TEST” so the T E and the S. I would like the stock to then go down by one on each of these letter. So T would go down to 98 as “TEST” has 2 T’s. E would go down to 99 and S down to 99 on stock

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your situation and goal as follows.

- As the search values, there are the cells "R7:S7".
- There are the data range in the cells "B2:O".

  - Row 2 is the header row.
  - Row 3 is the empty row.
  - From row 4, it the data range.
- You want to achieve the following flow using Google Apps Script.

  1. Search the column from the cell "S7".
  2. Split the value of "R7" for each character.
  3. Retrieve the rows from the retrieved column, which was retrieved by "S7", using the splitted values of "R7"
  4. Reduce `1` from the value of the right side of the retrieved column.

In order to achieve this, I would like to propose the following sample script. The flow of this script is as follows.

#### Flow:

1. Retrieve the values from the cells "R7:S7".
2. Retrieve the values from the cells "B2:O".
3. Retrieve the header row.
4. Create an object for searching each character from the cell "R7".
5. Reduce 1 from the the value of the right side of the retrieved column.
6. Put the calculated values to the column.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the container-bound script of Spreadsheet, and set the cells "R7:S7" and run the function of `StockUpdate()`.

```
function StockUpdate() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  // 1. Retrieve the values from the cells "R7:S7".
  const [reg, style] = sheet.getRange("R7:S7").getValues()[0].map(e => e.toUpperCase().trim());
  
  // 2. Retrieve the values from the cells "B2:O".
  const values = sheet.getRange("B2:O" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  
  // 3. Retrieve the header row.
  const index = values.shift().map(e => e.toUpperCase().trim()).indexOf(style);
  values.shift();  // Delete the empty row.
  
  if (index > -1) {
    
    // 4. Create an object for searching each character from the cell "R7".
    const obj = values.reduce((o, r, i) => Object.assign(o, {[r[index].toString().toUpperCase()]: i}), {});  // <--- Modified
    
    // 5. Reduce 1 from the the value of the right side of the retrieved column.
    [...reg].forEach(e => {
      if (e in obj) values[obj[e]][index + 1] -= 1;
    });
    const stoks = values.map(r => [r[index + 1]]);
    
    // 6. Put the calculated values to the column.
    sheet.getRange(4, 2 + index + 1, stoks.length, 1).setValues(stoks);
  
  } else {
    throw new Error("No style.");
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- **This sample script is for achieving the specification of your question and sample image. So when this specification is changed, the sample script might not be able to be used. So please be careful this. If you want to change the specification, please modify the script.**

#### References:

- [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: Will give it a try once I’m home 

Comment: Okay, so im getting the following error "TypeError: undefined is not a function (line 17, file "newcode")" @tanaike

Comment: However what you wrote is correct and exactly how i want it to work, just unsure on the error.

Comment: @Fallen Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, from `Okay, so im getting the following error "TypeError: undefined is not a function (line 17, file "newcode")"`, I cannot understand about your situation. Because in my environment, I can confirm that the script works. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand your current situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue. I'm glad.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, really appricate you helping me. Here is a link for a test sheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nCdYrYnV0Z8w_DkJqGiIfSCwYdGv5TwFI2hFb8084d0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Fallen Thank you for cooperating. I would like to confirm it.

Comment: is that link i attached okay ?

Comment: @Fallen Thank you for replying. I could understand about the reason of your issue. In your spreadsheet, I forgot that not only the alphabet characters, but also the numbers are used. By this, the error occurred at `toUpperCase()`. This is my mistake. I apologize for this. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: thats perfect mate, thank you so much ! am really sorry for the hard explaining of the message but you have achived exactly what i wanted ! thank you so much !!

Comment: @Fallen Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I could understand about the issue by your cooperation. Thank you, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217492/discussion-between-fallen-and-tanaike).

Comment: Hi Tanaike, me again lol sorry. Just wondering if you could help a little as you have done an awesome job helping me out.
Would there be a way at all so for our stock
the number 6 and 9 are the same however we monitor the stock using number 6
when the number 9 is typed it doesnt have anything to minus 1 off.
would there be a way for instance that when the number 9 is typed in cell R9 that it would minus 1 from the 6 stock?

Comment: @Fallen Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand what you want to do from your replying. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about your new issue, can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: I have made a post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62823867/change-value-of-another-number-within-a-script-for-one-number